# How can I redeem my free GTA San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

According to [this announcement](https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/61123/Download-The-Rockstar-Games-Launcher), I downloaded the launcher and when I opened it, I found out that GTA San Andreas is not for free. What am I missing? and How can I redeem it? Thank you,

Update : I'm already over 18 years old. I don't have issues like a bug or an error. It's available but not for FREE as they claimed on their website.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The announcement (see image below) [states](https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/61123/Download-The-Rockstar-Games-Launcher):

> Download Now and get a bonus FREE copy of Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas on PC **for a limited time**

This was posted September 17, 2019. **In all probability the giveaway has expired.**

[image: screenshot of the announcement]

Comment: Yup.  They have offered a lot of freebie games--most of them you have to claim in the week they are offered, they did a 12 days of Christmas thing where they had to be claimed in a 24 hour window.

Comment: Since the offer has expired, I think they should remove it from the website. Thanks for the answer. That was useful.

Comment: @user2824371: It's under "Newswire" on their website. You don't take old news off your website just because it's out of date. Update it, maybe, but not remove the article.

Answer (score 14):

Another [announcement](https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/61153/Red-Dead-Redemption-2-Coming-to-PC-November-5th) states the offer ended on October 8th 2019.

> For those yet to download the Rockstar Games Launcher, be sure to download by Tuesday October 8th to get Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas for free.